# Как через регулярное выражение заменить tabIndex="1" на tabIndex={1}?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Знатоки регулярных выражений, подскажите, как заменить tabIndex="1" на tabIndex={1}? JavaScript

Comment: @NowhereMan Это SO на русском, поэтому, думаю, надо заменить на русском, но с латинскими буквами :)

Comment: Мне больше интересно, зачем? Чего вы хотите добиться этой заменой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял что требуется:

```js
const str = `tabIndex="154"
center tabIndex="1" center
AtabIndex="1"
tabIndex="432"`;

const reg = /(?<=\btabIndex[ \t]*=[ \t]*)"(\d+)"/g
//Позитивный просмотр назад (?<=...) не захватывает символы, лишь проверяет их наличие
//[ \t]* ноль и более пробелов или символов табуляции
//(...) захватываемая группа, данные будут возвращаться в $1
//если кроме цифр могут быть любые данные, то заменить "(\d+)" на "([^"]+)"
console.log(str.replace(reg,"{$1}"))
```